# Khipu, libreria de front sin Jquery

Tags: javascript

Alguien ha trabajado con Khipu sin usar la librería que ellos tienen?

https://khipu.com/es_CL/page/biblioteca-javascript

En ella indican:

```
Lo primero que debemos hacer es incluir jQuery:
<script src=“//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js”></script>
Luego incluimos la biblioteca de khipu.
<script src=“//storage.googleapis.com/installer/khipu.js”></script>
```

Pero estoy en una web con React, y no quiero añadir jQuery para poder controlar el retorno al comercio después de que se haga el pago, pero no he pillado alguna forma más actual que no sea con la librería de Khipu

Comment: Tendrías que traducir su biblioteca, ya que según la veo el uso de Jquery es interno dentro de su archivo js, por eso lo requiere.

Comment: Claro, además usan internamente `atmosphere.js` para manejar los websockets, y creo que esa requiere jquery. Maldición